# How to tail the logs of long running python script invoked via ansible

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

We are running a python script via ansible. The script takes around 45 mins to complete and the logging is in verbose mode. But the issue is we get to know the result only after 45 minutes or if the script fails.

```yaml
- name: Run a python script
  shell: |
    cd /tmp/
    python {{script_name}} {{branch}} {{ script_action_arg_test }} >>  output.txt
```

I have tried the above approach, the python process keeps running but does not log anything to output.txt
Is there a way to capture the verbose logs of the script in ansible itself?

Comment: You can run it with `cd /tmp/
    python {{script_name}} {{branch}} {{ script_action_arg_test }} > some_file.log` and it will capture the output to a file

Comment: @Tamir, i just tried the approach but it doesn't seem to log anything to the file output.txt even though process is running

Comment: Is the process printing to stdout? or something else?

Comment: When we run it on terminal its definately redirected to output.txt but when we do the same thing in ansible module, i am not so sure. Hence asked this question. @Tamir

Comment: 1. Don't do `cd /tmp`, rather use [`chdir: /tmp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/shell_module.html#parameter-chdir) in your task. 2. For the problem at hand, this is not how Ansible works, and you should not expect a "lively feedback" from a task. This question is somehow close to what you are asking here: https://serverfault.com/questions/958952/ansible-task-write-to-local-log-file

Comment: You would need to run that task with `async`, then loop over an `include` file that has a task that gets the tail of the file (ten lines or so) and another that dumps it with `debug`.

Comment: @Jack, thanks a lot. Would you be able to give it as an example?  It would be really helpful

Comment: Yes, but not right now.  I've got some work to do for the church food bank.  I'll be back in a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

OK -- it's ugly.  BUT, Ansible is for automation -- fire and forget, and is not designed for people to see what's going on in real time.

Now, use `ansible-galaxy init my-cool-role` in your roles directory to create the role.  Then, these are the files you will put in the role:

`tasks/main.yml`:

```
---
- name: Copy script to remote host
  copy:
    src: long_script.sh
    dest: long_script.sh
    mode: 0755

- name: Run script in async
  shell: ./long_script.sh > long_script.out
  async: 1000
  poll: 0
  register: long_task

- name: Include monitoring tasks
  include_tasks: monitor.yml
  loop: "{{ range(0, 100, 1)|list }}"
```

`tasks/monitor.yml`

```
---
- set_fact:
    done: "{{ 'DONE' == tail.stdout_lines[9] | default(false) }}"

- debug:
    var: tail.stdout_lines[9]

- debug:
    var: done

- meta: end_play
  when: done|bool

- name: Get last ten lines
  shell: sleep 5; tail long_script.out
  register: tail

- name: Show lines
  debug:
    var: tail.stdout_lines
```

`files/long_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( ii=0; ii<50; ii++ )); do
  echo -n "$ii: "
  date
  sleep 1
done
echo DONE
```

This assumes that the long task is the last thing you're doing, because it ends the play.  Note that you have to have enough loops to cover the expected time it il take the task to run.  If you need to do something after this, just put another play in the playbook.  Good luck.

Comment: thanks a lot Jack for this amazing explanation. I would definitely try this. You are awesome :)  