# Can Ansible playbook run an infinite loop?

Tags: python, ansible

I want to run this Python script using Ansible Playbook and watch it every time my script prints "I'm alive" text.
is this possible?

python_script.py

```
import time
 
while True:
    print("I'm alive")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Yes, since the while coundition is true and it's boolean is never changed it will run as long as the notebook is up.

Comment: No, such is and will not be possible out-of-box and without enhancing Ansible Core functionality.

Comment: You question has actually two different questions. Can the loop be infinite? Well, yes. Can one see the output on each iteration? No, see U880D's answer.

Answer (score 2):

> ***I want to run this Python script using Ansible Playbook and watch it every time my script prints "I'm alive" text. Is this possible?***

No, such is and will not be possible out-of-box and without enhancing Ansible Core functionality.

[Ansible modules (like `shell`, `command`, `script`, etc. ...) normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#stdout). This will be collected and sent back to the Control Node after the task has been finished. Than, after that, [You can create variables from the output of an Ansible task with the task keyword `register`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables).

Therefore you may have a look into

**Similar Q&A**

- [How can I get the output of an Ansible play as it is being run?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76341703/6771046)
- [Ansible: How to display realtime Shell `stdout`?](https://serverfault.com/a/972664/448950)
- [Provide mechanism for streaming logs from modules](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/92)
- [Debug info from Ansible Custom Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54448411/6771046)
- [How can I show progress for a long-running Ansible task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773566/6771046)

---

Based on a comment

> ***Can Ansible playbook run an infinite loop?***

this could be considered as a fire and forget task. In order to do so one may have a look into [Asynchronous actions and polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html) and [Run tasks concurrently: `poll = 0`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#run-tasks-concurrently-poll-0)

> *If you want to run multiple tasks in a playbook concurrently, use `async` `with` poll set to 0. When you set `poll: 0`, Ansible starts the task and immediately **moves on to the next task without waiting for a result**.*

Please take note that for something like

```yaml
  - script: python_script.py
    async: 60
    poll: 0
    register: result
```

```yaml
TASK [script] ******************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: async is not supported for this task.
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to run command on Remote Host in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39355842/6771046)
- [How to tail the logs of long running Python script invoked via Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64814601/6771046)
- [How to print a message for each `async` `loop` item?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75359270/6771046)

and many more ...